# "Invalid VCS root mapping" en android studio

Tags: android-studio

Un proyecto de android studio me da error porque "el directorio es registrado como una ruta de Git pero no tiene repositorios Git". ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto sin crear un nuevo proyecto?

Answer (score 3):

En tu IDE entra a **File** > **Settings** > **Version Control**

Te saldrá una tabla que dice Directory y VCS (columnas de la tabla), da clic sobre **VCS** y elige **NONE**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias comando!!! funciono